# I am facing below reacr-native app crash issues

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
at com.imagepicker.utils.MediaUtils.readExifInterface(MediaUtils.java:267)
at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.onActivityResult(ImagePickerModule.java:465)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onActivityResult(ReactContext.java:288)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(ReactInstanceManager.java:738)
at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactDelegate.java:90)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactActivityDelegate.java:112)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onActivityResult(ReactActivity.java:68)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4552)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1715)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)

Comment: I have used react-native-image-picker on my project and i am facing this above crash, anyone please help me

Comment: Please add the code where and how you used react-native-image-picker ?

Comment: let imagePath;
ImagePicker.showImagePicker({ title: 'Add Photo',
  quality: 0.6,
  maxWidth: 800,
  maxHeight: 800,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'image',
  }}, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        return;
      } else if (response.error) {
        Alert.alert('Sorry, We need file storage permissions to make this work');
      } else {
        imagePath = response.uri;
      }
    })